# How to use XSLT when my XML contains a Prefix?

Tags: xslt

I have this XML below and I'm trying to print the content of the `MyField` element using XSLT. Unfortunately I can't make it work. Can you help me fix my XSLT?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my_xsl.xsl"?>
<ns:Collection>
  <Load>
    <Item>
      <MyField>Please Print Me</MyField>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns:Collection/Load/Item/MyField" />
```

Comment: Add namespace in xml for `ns:` also same in xslt at declaration

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is not **namespace well formed** because the namespace prefix "ns" has not been bound to any namespace URI.

XSLT cannot process XML input unless it is **namespace well formed**.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespace for ns: in the root element